# Open a .raw file as text in less

Tags: command-line, less

The output of my program has a .raw file extension. If I try to open this with `less` I get:

```
No isoinfo available
Install mkisofs to view ISO images
```

The file isn't an image file, it's just text. Is there a way to tell `less` that the file should be opened as plain text?

Comment: try with strings command: strings file.raw|less

Comment: If I really want to see what's in a file, I use `more` rather than `less`.

Comment: To really see what's in a file, I use `od` ;-).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The attempt to use `isoinfo` comes from `lesspipe`, which is generally used as a helper for `less` via the `LESSOPEN` variable.

Running

```
LESSOPEN= less file.raw
```

will open `file.raw` without interpretation.

Answer (score 18):

Another option which doesn't involve setting any variables is to pipe the data through `less` instead of letting `less` open the file for you.

```
$ cat file.raw | less
```

or

```
$ less <file.raw
```

would do the trick.

Comment: This is also great suggestion; if I could accept two answers I would also accept this.

Comment: Using redirections into `less` has a couple of disadvantages: `less` needs to buffer everything, so it will use more memory (unless `-B` is specified); it won't know about the file name, and the size will only be available once it's finished reading all the data.